# How to load hex file into NXP LPC2148 microcontroller using lpc21isp on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, arm, serial-port

[image]

hello friends , I am new to lpc21isp please help me
Please see the attached image.
While I am trying to load hex file into NXP LPC2148 I am getting this error.Someone please tell me if we have to change any settings before we using lpc21isp on Linux(Ubuntu 14.04).
I am using LPC2148 development board [Development Board](http://www.nex-robotics.com/lpc2148-development-board/arm7-lpc2148-development-board.html)

We need to press boot switch first ,then press reset switch, then release reset switch and release boot switch to put it into boot-loader mode while loading hex file on lpc2148 dev board.(Same as LPC2148-BlueBoard).
Does that make any difference while loading hex file using lpc21isp on Linux(Ubuntu 14.04)??

Answer (score 1):

you are giving clock frequency as 12000(12K) , it should be 12000000(12M since board has 12M crystal).
please make sure TX and RX pins are properly connected.